# how to create custom product options that there price is dependent on another?

Tags: event-observer, custom-options

Is there a way to create custom product options in a way that the one's price is dependent on another *(without using the configurable product)* ? and i'm using only custom options.

Like for example we have product that have a custom option **Print Type** a radio input having some options [A-Type, B-Type, C-Type] and one more option **Sizes** [XXX,XX,X,L,X,S].

**And my question:**
If we change **Print Type**, the price of sizes should reflect according to the selected **Print Type**. Should i have to use a observer to bind option prices to each other ??

Comment: why you don't want to use configurable product?

Comment: As we have 100k products in our magento catalog each having around 15 Custom options with aprox 500 inputs/radio

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to set the price of custom option look at below image.

go to **Catalog => Product => Add New / Edit => Custom Option**

[image]